# Removing &nbsp BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a timetable webpage at the moment and the problem I am having with the print out is that there is mental about of dead space. This is due to the tag I am looking at in a lot of cases has the '&nbsp' as a text entry. That space is there for when we have no classes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://timetable.ait.ie/reporting/individual;student+set;id;AL%5FKNTWM%5F7%5F3%0D%0A?t=student+set+individual&days=1-5&weeks=&periods=3-20&template=student+set+individual"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'lxml')
sources = soup.findAll('table')
for source in sources:
    for tr in source.findAll('tr'):
        for td in tr.findAll('td',{"rowspan":True}):
            if td.text is u'\xa0': continue             
            else:
                print td.text
```

That is the code I have so far and I have tried `if td.text is '&nbsp': continue` and `if td.text == '&nbsp': continue` and `if td.text == u'\xa0': continue` but none of these options work for me. This is part of the html code I am trying to parse.

```
<!-- START ROW OUTPUT -->
                <tr >
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" rowspan='1' >Mon</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='2' rowspan='1' >
                        <!-- START OBJECT-CELL -->
                        <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                            <col align='left' />
                            <tr>
                                <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>Networks Security 3</font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                            <col align='left' />
                            <col align='right' />
                            <tr>
                                <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>W206</font></td>
                                <td align='right'><font color='#000080'>Bennett, Tom</font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                            <col align='left' />
                            <tr>
                                <td align='left'><font color='#000080'>3-9, 11-14</font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END OBJECT-CELL -->
```

As you can see there is multiple 'td' tags that have &nbsp as an option but later I will need to count these non-breaking spaces to figure out times for classes. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Please ignore the rowspan in the for loop I copied the code over and made a small mistake of leaving it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''
        <!-- START ROW OUTPUT -->
                <tr >
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" rowspan='1' >Mon</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='2' rowspan='1' >
                        <!-- START OBJECT-CELL -->
                        <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                            <col align='left' />
                            <tr>
                                <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>Networks Security 3</font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                            <col align='left' />
                            <col align='right' />
                            <tr>
                                <td align='left'><font color='#000000'>W206</font></td>
                                <td align='right'><font color='#000080'>Bennett, Tom</font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                            <col align='left' />
                            <tr>
                                <td align='left'><font color='#000080'>3-9, 11-14</font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END OBJECT-CELL -->'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

tds = soup.find_all(name='td', text=re.compile(r"^\S"))
for td in tds:
    print(td)
```

out:

```
<td rowspan="1" style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;">Mon</td>
<td align="left"><font color="#000000">Networks Security 3</font></td>
<td align="left"><font color="#000000">W206</font></td>
<td align="right"><font color="#000080">Bennett, Tom</font></td>
<td align="left"><font color="#000080">3-9, 11-14</font></td>
```